# Cumulative Sum in MySQL with ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I want to have a cumulative column in MySQL. When I use the SQL command without ORDER BY clause, it is Ok. But with ORDER BY clause the result is wrong.

My SQL statement is:

```
SET @LastSumFee := 1000;
SELECT HioId, ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx, InputFee, OutputFee, (@LastSumFee := @LastSumFee + InputFee - OutputFee) AS SumFee
FROM HsbInOutView
WHERE HnId = 9 OR LHnId = 9
LIMIT 5;
```

For this sql the result is ok (this result is produced with phpMyAdmin):

```
HioId   ApplyDate   ApplyTime   Idx     InputFee    OutputFee   SumFee  
168     1381/10/10  00:00:00    11      1085945     0           1086945
169     1381/10/21  00:00:00    12      0           600000      486945
170     1381/10/02  00:00:00    10      0           700000      -213055
171     1381/10/01  00:00:00    9       0           600000      -813055
180     1381/05/26  00:00:00    3       782040      0           -31015
```

Now if I add ORDER BY to SQL command like this:

```
SET @LastSumFee := 1000;
SELECT HioId, ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx, InputFee, OutputFee, (@LastSumFee := @LastSumFee + InputFee - OutputFee) AS SumFee
FROM HsbInOutView
WHERE HnId = 9 OR LHnId = 9
ORDER BY ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx
LIMIT 5;
```

I get this wrong result (this result is produced with phpMyAdmin):

```
HioId   ApplyDate   ApplyTime   Idx     InputFee    OutputFee   SumFee  
193     1380/08/08  00:00:00    1       50000       0           4444879
1334    1380/08/08  00:00:00    36      0           50000       -6897369
194     1381/04/30  00:00:00    2       889100      0           5333979
1169    1381/04/30  00:00:00    127     0           889100      15774756
180     1381/05/26  00:00:00    3       782040      0           -31015
```

I expect the result below:

```
HioId   ApplyDate   ApplyTime   Idx     InputFee    OutputFee   SumFee  
193     1380/08/08  00:00:00    1       50000       0           51000
1334    1380/08/08  00:00:00    36      0           50000       1000
194     1381/04/30  00:00:00    2       889100      0           890100
1169    1381/04/30  00:00:00    127     0           889100      1000
180     1381/05/26  00:00:00    3       782040      0           783040
```

Comment: I have removed PHP tag; as this question does not seem to involve it.

Comment: Can you add the result you'r trying to get?

Comment: Nice job on this question; you included a lot of information we'd need to answer it.  If you want to take it to the next level, create an sql fiddle that has example data too.

Comment: I edit the Post to show my expectation.

Comment: Are you using a new enough version of MySQL that it supports window functions?

Comment: I'm using from MySQL Server version: 5.6.16

Answer (score 0):

In many of the more recent versions of MySQL, you need to materialize the table as a derived table for this to work:

```
SELECT HioId, ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx, InputFee, OutputFee, 
       (@LastSumFee := @LastSumFee + InputFee - OutputFee) AS SumFee
FROM (SELECT v.*
      FROM HsbInOutView v
      WHERE HnId = 9 OR LHnId = 9
      ORDER BY ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx
     ) v CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @LastSumFee := 1000) params
LIMIT 5;
```

Of course,

```
( 1000 + SUM(InputFee - OutputFee) OVER (ORDER BY ApplyDate, ApplyTime, Idx) ) as SumFee
```

is much simpler.